# Alterar informações no banco de dados através de PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Fiz dois arquivos com o objetivo de **alterar** as informações de um item com uma id especifica, o código funciona corretamente, porém as informações não são alteradas. Podem me ajudar? Segue abaixo os códigos:

### editar.php:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="formulario.html">Cadastrar um ativo</a>
<br>
<a href="listar.php">Listar Ativos</a>
<br><br>
<form method="POST" action="formulario_editar.php">
    ID: <br><input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
    Empresa: <br><input type="text" name="empresa"><br><br>
    Filial: <br><input type="text" name="filial"><br><br>
    Segmento: <br><input type="text" name="segmento"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Editar">
</form> 

<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

### formulario_editar.php:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<a href="formulario.html">Cadastrar um ativo</a>
<br>
<a href="listar.php">Listar Ativos</a>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "tedinfo1_app";
$username = "tedinfo1_app";
$password = "123456789";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$filial = $_POST['filial'];
$segmento = $_POST['segmento']; 

$result_empresa = "UPDATE ativos SET empresa = '$empresa' THERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_empresa = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_empresa);

$result_filial = "UPDATE ativos SET filial = '$filial' THERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_filial = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_filial);

$result_segmento = "UPDATE ativos SET segmento = '$segmento' THERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_segmento = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_segmento);

echo "Ativo editado com súcesso!";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você escreveu ***THERE*** mas deveria ser ***WHERE***. Segue código alterado:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "tedinfo1_app";
$username = "tedinfo1_app";
$password = "123456789";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
$filial = $_POST['filial'];
$segmento = $_POST['segmento']; 

$result_empresa = "UPDATE ativos SET empresa = '$empresa' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_empresa = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_empresa);

$result_filial = "UPDATE ativos SET filial = '$filial' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_filial = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_filial);

$result_segmento = "UPDATE ativos SET segmento = '$segmento' WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_segmento = mysqli_query ($conn, $result_segmento);

echo "Ativo editado com súcesso!";

?>
```

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: @Ruan não esqueça de verificar se o campo do POST está vazio com o isset ...